# Iterate through a conditional for_each map of strings

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

Trying to put something together to get passed a limitation of the tfe plugin.

I have 200+ workspaces that I manage with a variable in Terraform Cloud that I need to update. All workspaces that I need to update start with "dev-workspace" in this case.

I have a data block with the following:

```
data "tfe_workspace_ids" "all" {
  names        = ["*"]
  organization = "myorganization"
}
```

I can't do a wildcard search for these workspaces due to a limitation of the module. This data block returns a map of strings that include *all* of my workspaces:

```
aa = {
    "dev-workspace-1"                   = "ws-anonymized"
    "dev-workspace-2"                   = "ws-ws-anonymized"
    "dev-workspace-3"                   = "ws-ws-anonymized"
    "test-workspace-1"                  = "ws-ws-anonymized"
    "prod-workspace-1"                  = "ws-ws-anonymized"
}
```

My problem is that I need to take this map of strings and filter it down to just return the ones that have "dev-workspace" in the key. I've tried something like the following:

```
resource "tfe_variable" "dev-workspace" {
  for_each = contains(data.tfe_workspace_ids.all.ids, "dev-workspace")

  key = "access_key"
  value = "XXXX"
  category = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.value
  sensitive = true
  description = "AWS IAM secret access key."
}
```

But it doesn't look like you can use `contains` in this manner with `for_each`:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on main.tf line 16, in resource "tfe_variable" "dev-workspace":
  16:   for_each = contains(data.tfe_workspace_ids.all.ids, "dev-workspace")
    |----------------
    | data.tfe_workspace_ids.all.ids is map of string with 284 elements

Call to function "contains" failed: argument must be list, tuple, or set.
```

I'm not really sure what to do here, but have tried this several ways and can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter, your resource could be (you have to change `var.aa` to the value of `data.tfe_workspace_ids` which produces the input map):

```
variable "aa" {

  default = {
      "dev-workspace-1"                   = "ws-anonymized"
      "dev-workspace-2"                   = "ws-ws-anonymized"
      "dev-workspace-3"                   = "ws-ws-anonymized"
      "test-workspace-1"                  = "ws-ws-anonymized"
      "prod-workspace-1"                  = "ws-ws-anonymized"
  }
}

resource "tfe_variable" "dev-workspace" {

  for_each = {for k, v in var.aa:
              k => v if length(regexall("dev-workspace", k)) > 0}

  key = "access_key"
  value = "XXXX"
  category = "terraform"
  workspace_id = each.value
  sensitive = true
  description = "AWS IAM secret access key."
}
```